# Toggle div only when button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

jQuery newbie here, I'm hoping someone can help.

I have a function when a div with the class `.ventures-minorities` is clicked, it changes height onclick to show / hide `.logos-wrapper` - and the button with the class `.expander` toggles text accordingly - "Learn more" to "Close" - when clicked.

The button and div is working and toggling as expected,  but how do I make the `.logos-wrapper` only appear when the `.expander` button is clicked?

Right now the `.logos-wrapper` container is able to toggle when I click anywhere around it, which is probably linked to the `.ventures-minorities` container being targeted onclick but I don't know how to make the `.logos-wrapper` toggle **only when** the `.expander` button is clicked.

This is an issue because when the div is clicked outside of the button, it toggles, but the button text doesn't. I'm unsure of how to tie these two together.

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.expander .elementor-button-text').on('click', function() {
      if ($.trim($(this).text()) == 'Learn more') {
        $(this).text('Close');
      } 
      else {
        $(this).text('Learn more');
      }
    });

    $(".ventures-minorities").on('click', function() {
      $(this).find(".logos-wrapper").toggleClass("sized");
    });

  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.logos-wrapper {
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}

.sized {
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}

.ventures-minorities {
  padding: 50px 0;
}

button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: darkslateblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  border: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: tomato;
  color: #000;
}

button:active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ventures-minorities">
  <button class="expander">
    <span class="elementor-button-text">Learn more</span>
  </button>

  <div class="logos-wrapper">content</div>
</div>

<div class="ventures-minorities">
  <button class="expander">
    <span class="elementor-button-text">Learn more</span>
  </button>

  <div class="logos-wrapper">content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply define the event listener for the buttons `.expander` instead of the parent container `.ventures-minorities`.

To get the toggle to work, you need to use the method `parent()` before you find the `.logos-wrapper` because `$(this)` is now the button, a child of `.ventures-minorities`:

```js
$(this).parent().find(".logos-wrapper").toggleClass("sized");
```

**Working example:**

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.expander .elementor-button-text').on('click', function() {
      if ($.trim($(this).text()) == 'Learn more') {
        $(this).text('Close');
      } 
      else {
        $(this).text('Learn more');
      }
    });

    $(".expander").on('click', function() {
      $(this).parent().find(".logos-wrapper").toggleClass("sized");
    });

  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.logos-wrapper {
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}

.sized {
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}

.ventures-minorities {
  padding: 50px 0;
}

button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: darkslateblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  border: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: tomato;
  color: #000;
}

button:active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ventures-minorities">
  <button class="expander">
    <span class="elementor-button-text">Learn more</span>
  </button>
  
  <div class="logos-wrapper">content</div>
</div>

<div class="ventures-minorities">
  <button class="expander">
    <span class="elementor-button-text">Learn more</span>
  </button>
  
  <div class="logos-wrapper">content</div>
</div>
```

---

In this case you could combine the two event listeners.

To get the text exchange to work, you have to `find()` the span, that holds the text, at best with a separate var, to prevent repetition:

```js
$('.expander').on('click', function() {
  const text_span = $(this).find(".elementor-button-text");
      
  if ($.trim(text_span.text()) == 'Learn more') {...
```

**Working example:**

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.expander').on('click', function() {
      const text_span = $(this).find(".elementor-button-text");
      
      if ($.trim(text_span.text()) == 'Learn more') {
        text_span.text('Close');
      } 
      else {
        text_span.text('Learn more');
      }
      
      $(this).parent().find(".logos-wrapper").toggleClass("sized");
    });

  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.logos-wrapper {
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}

.sized {
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}

.ventures-minorities {
  padding: 50px 0;
}

button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: darkslateblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  border: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: tomato;
  color: #000;
}

button:active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ventures-minorities">
  <button class="expander">
    <span class="elementor-button-text">Learn more</span>
  </button>
  
  <div class="logos-wrapper">content</div>
</div>

<div class="ventures-minorities">
  <button class="expander">
    <span class="elementor-button-text">Learn more</span>
  </button>
  
  <div class="logos-wrapper">content</div>
</div>
```